# Table view isnt working correctly.

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

I am trying to create a table view pragmatically(no xib and no storyboards), but the food array isn`t showing up in table view at all. I will post all my code in view controller.

Viewcontroller.h

```
  @interface searchViewController :     ViewController<UITextFieldDelegate,UISearchBarDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>{
  NSMutableArray * getterms;
}

 @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray* allTableData;
 @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray* filteredTableData;
 @property (nonatomic, assign) bool isFiltered;
 @property (nonatomic, retain) UITableView *tableView;
```

Viewcontroller.m

```
  -(void)viewDidLoad{
   UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 10.0, 1000.0, 200.0) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
[self.view addSubview:tableView];
  self.tableView.dataSource = self;

     allTableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                [[Food alloc] initWithName:@"Steak" andDescription:@"Rare"],
                [[Food alloc] initWithName:@"Steak" andDescription:@"Medium"],
                [[Food alloc] initWithName:@"Salad" andDescription:@"Caesar"],
                [[Food alloc] initWithName:@"Salad" andDescription:@"Bean"],
                [[Food alloc] initWithName:@"Fruit" andDescription:@"Apple"],
                [[Food alloc] initWithName:@"Potato" andDescription:@"Baked"],
                [[Food alloc] initWithName:@"Potato" andDescription:@"Mashed"],
                [[Food alloc] initWithName:@"Bread" andDescription:@"White"],
                [[Food alloc] initWithName:@"Bread" andDescription:@"Brown"],
                [[Food alloc] initWithName:@"Hot Dog" andDescription:@"Beef"],
                [[Food alloc] initWithName:@"Hot Dog" andDescription:@"Chicken"],
                [[Food alloc] initWithName:@"Hot Dog" andDescription:@"Veggie"],
                [[Food alloc] initWithName:@"Pizza" andDescription:@"Pepperonni"],
                nil ];
           }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *MYCellIdentifier = @"MyCellIdentifier";

UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MYCellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:MYCellIdentifier];

Food* food;
if(isFiltered)
    food = [filteredTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
else
    food = [allTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.textLabel.text = food.name;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = food.description;

return cell;

  }
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
   {
return 1;
   }


     - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
int rowCount;
if(self.isFiltered)
    rowCount = filteredTableData.count;
else
    rowCount = allTableData.count;

return rowCount;
 }

    - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

if (self) {

}
return self;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you never assign your table view to your controller, add

```
self.tableView = tableView
```

as a second line in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: OMG I added it, but not on right line LOL. You will be rewarded with the check mark, just need to wait 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the tableView's delegate.

From [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UITableView):

> A UITableView object **must have** an object that acts as a data source and **an object that acts as a delegate**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure cellForRowAtIndexPath is actually being called (use NSlog or breakpoint to check), if not, you have not set the UITableViewController's tableView to the tableView it is controlling, or you have not set your dataSource Delegate.